# Exportar package

Tags: r

Pessoal eu criei um pacote no R, já está com o a documentação, com o `@export` em cada função, peço para o `Rstudio` criar o pacote e tudo certinho. Mas quando importo o pacote ele lê os documentos todos, os helps de todas funções, mas não lê propriamente a função. Ou seja, `?funcao` funcionada, mas `funcao(x)` diz que não encontrou a função.

## Edição 1.

Sendo preciso, está assim, tenho as funções dentro do `NAMESPACE` criado pelo `roxygen2` dessa forma:

```
S3method(plot,polygon)
export(convex.verification)
export(polygon.intersection)
export(polygon.transformation)
export(polygonal.correlation)
export(polygonal.covariance)
export(polygonal.mean)
```

E a função que não é reconhecida no check é apenas a `plot.polygon`

Alguém tem uma ideia do que seja?

Comment: vê se no NAMESPACE tem o nome de todas as funções, é esse arquivo que controla o que aparece e o que não.

Comment: Como sempre, o capítulo do Hadley sobre NAMESPACE explica muito bem o que ele é, como funciona e porque existe, e ainda dá várias dicas. http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

Comment: Confira também se você usou a sintaxe certa da notação do Roxygen2 (`#' @export` logo antes da definição da função).

Comment: Encontrei o erro, está no `roxygen2` está instalando com erro, tentei reinstalar, mas não vai, aparece a mensagem: `Warning in install.packages :  cannot remove prior installation of package roxygen2`.

Comment: Geralmente se você reiniciar o seu computador esse problema de remover a instalação do pacote é corrigido. Isso acontece muitas vezes porque tem alguma sessão do R usando a pasta. Mas o `NAMESPACE` tava errado mesmo?

Comment: Sim, quando `check`, ele pede uma função chamada `hello` que não existe no pacote e aborta, mas roda toda documentação certinho só que as funções ficam como inexistentes.

Comment: E uma função que existe não é reconhecida.

Comment: Editei adicionando mais informações.

Comment: Não entendo muito de `S3Methods`, mas acho que o problema está aí. A ideia deles é que funcionem sem ser necessário usar plot.polygon, que fosse apenas `plot` em um objeto com classe polygon. Não sei se o roxygen2 segue essa ideia e deixa de exportar a função normalmente.

Comment: Você já tentou usar só `plot` em um objeto com classe `polygon`?

Comment: Tentei, dá erro. Essa função plota vários polígonos sobrepostos ligando os pontos.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41778/discussion-between-daniel-falbel-and-wagner-jorge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o livro [R-packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html)

> Object names  Variable and function names should be lowercase. Use an
>   underscore (_) to separate words within a name (reserve . for S3
>   methods). Camel case is a legitimate alternative, but be consistent!
>   Generally, variable names should be nouns and function names should be
>   verbs. Strive for names that are concise and meaningful (this is not
>   easy!).

Destaco a frase:

> Use an
>   underscore (_) to separate words within a name (reserve . for S3
>   methods).

Ou seja: *Use underline (_) para separar palavras no nome (.. de um objeto) (reserve . para métodos S3)*.

Não sei exatamente como funciona o S3 e nem como o roxygen2 se comporta na presença dele. Meu chute é que ele não exporta a função, só o método. Portanto,
a sua função talvez funcionasse em um objeto com classe `polygon`.

Exemplo:

```
class(obj) <- "polygon"
plot(obj)
```

**Se não for isso que você deseja, tente substituir o ponto no nome da função por underline (_).**